# C# & MongoDb - Como fazer filtro em documento filho?

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-csharp

Estou iniciando minhas aventuras no MongoDB e estou com um problema especificamente com a filtragem de documentos. O modelo da minha aplicação:

```
public class MatrizCurricular
{
    [BsonId]     
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string Curso { get; set; }       
    public IList<Semestre> Semestres { get; set; }
}
public class Semestre
{
    public int NumSemestre { get; set; }     
    public IList<Disciplina> Disciplinas { get; set; }
}
public class Disciplina
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

}
```

Como cada **MatrizCurricular**, possui suas próprias disciplinas, faço uma consulta dentro da mesma por uma disciplina que possua esse mesmo _id

```
//Crio uma consulta           
var filter = Builders<MatrizCurricular>.Filter.Eq("semestres.disciplinas._id", new ObjectId(id));
//Executo a consulta
var results = bd.MatrizCurricular.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Resultado:

```
[
{
    "_id": "sdfsdfsdf",
    "curso": "Administração",
    "semestres": [
        {
            "numSemestre": 1,                
            "disciplinas": [
                {
                    "_id": "asdasdasd",
                    "nome": "Administração financeira"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "paeiutaiurt",
                    "nome": "Teoria Geral da Administração"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "ajshgdajsh",
                    "nome": "Matemática"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "numSemestre": 2,            
            "disciplinas": [
                {
                    "_id": "6hti7d3dt7dwht67",
                    "nome": "Macroeconomia"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "d8u9dm7or7yu4t4e6",
                    "nome": "Raciocínio lógico"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "s8ory7niw3i7hn",
                    "nome": "Teoria da organização"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

O problema é que quando executo essa consulta, o resultado que eu tenho é o documento inteiro de **MatrizCurricular** que contém a **Disciplina** desejada, mas com todas os outros documentos **Disciplina** e **Semestre** parentes. Consigo contornar a situação fazendo uma consulta usando Linq depois que os dados já foram trazidos do banco, mas essa claramente não é a melhor opção

Existe alguma forma de trazer, por uma consulta direta com o banco somente um documento do tipo **Disciplina**?

Comment: como seria o resultado desejado Wender?

Comment: @LucasCosta algo como: {
                    "_id": "d8u9dm7or7yu4t4e6",
                    "nome": "Raciocínio lógico"
                }